# Why does an Ohmic contact contain non rectifying junction?

Tags: pn-junction

I would like to know a simple explanation for the term 'Ohmic Contact'.I looked in wikipedia but I couldn't get what actually it means.I couldn't even get what do you mean by non rectifying junction.Could anyone help me.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohmic_contact has a more detailed explanation, can you tell more details where are your confusion? More concretely.

Comment: @diverger:Thanks for your comments.I have confusion with the term 'non-rectifying junction'.Could you explain this junction in simple terms.

Comment: "non-rectifying junction" = connection where current can flow the same in both directions. If contact between different types of materials there can be a rectifying junction (like a galena cats-whisker crystal diode). A diode does not allow current to flow the same in both directions. Ohmic contact means taking care to avoid accidentally creating an unwanted diode where two different material conductors meet.

Comment: @MarkU:Thanks.Now I got an idea of 'Ohmic Contact'.But how were they able to allow current flow in both directions in transistor's terminal(s)?Also how the term 'non-rectifying' came?I think rectifying means converting an ac to dc.

Comment: @justin: You can also think rectifier to "make the bi-direction current, flows in only one direction". When you give it a AC, only current in one direction can flow throgh it.

Comment: a rectifier is simply another name for a diode.

Comment: @diverger:Okay.But how did they made an 'Ohmic Contact'?Is it by the property of metal used in the creation of terminal of transistor?

Comment: @MarkU:Okay.But do you know how they made an 'Ohmic Contact'.What properties of the terminal made the current to flow in both directions in the transistor?

Comment: @justin: When we talk Ohmic contact, we usually implies there are two matearials (usually a metal to a semiconductor) need to form a junction. And the junction need to conduct in bi-direction. The basic is not to form the depletion of the semiconductor near the junction.

Comment: ...according to paragraph 3 of the Wikipedia article, metal-to-metal is already Ohmic. So the term Ohmic is only used for metal-to-semiconductor junctions, where it's hard to avoid making a Schottky diode (rectifier) junction.

Comment: @MarkU:Is there an metal(terminal) only at the semiconductor junction?Isn't it there at Emitter and Collector terminal.How did they made an non-rectifier junction?

Comment: I don't understand. This is all about metal-to-semiconductor junction. So yes, there is metal there, and yes the metal-to-semiconductor junction is what they're talking about. Reading between the lines it sounds like this must be for a class on integrated circuit technology? This topic has to do with how an IC silicon chip is connected to its leadframe pins to get to the PCB. The IC is made of semiconductor (which is brittle), but the contact packaging is made of metal (because it has to be flexible). So semiconductor must contact metal at some point to get signals out of IC.

Comment: @MarkU:Okay.I got your point.But if an metal and metal is connected and current is passed through any one whether current would flow in both directions?I would like to know really whether current flows in one direction or both directions when metals are connected to each other and current is given to any one?Really I'm asking are we trying to make current flow in both directions or it naturally flows in both directions?

Comment: Do you not understand the term I-V curve in the Wikipedia article? In metals the I-V curve is **linear**, i.e. follows Ohm's Law, so the connection is Ohmic. Current CAN flow in either direction. Positive voltage causes current to flow one direction, negative voltage causes current to flow the other direction. Not at the same time obviously. But in a semiconductor the I-V curve is nonlinear. In the IC industry we don't want that, we want the metal-semiconductor junction to behave like an Ohmic connection (linear I-V curve), and that's what the whole article is about, because that's hard to do.

Comment: @MarkU:Could you tell me how could you make the non linear I-V curve in semiconductor to a linear one.Is this done by the addition of anything?

Comment: That's a separate question involving solid-state physics and materials engineering. Way beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: @MarkU:Okay.Sorry for the question.Should I post a new queston or should I leave it for now?

Answer (score 2):

When ever you put two material together that have a different work function, they will form a junction which acts as a diode/rectifier.  So the equivalent circuit diagram becomes "A' or "B" below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBzEp7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Either of those scenarios yields a device that isn't very useful, in fact it can't be used.  Ideally you want to make sure that you contact to the device looks like a resistor (ideally a zero ohm resistor, or at very least a very low value resistor) and NOT a diode. I'm making the assumption here that you'll understand *why* having diodes in series with your transistor is a bad, bad thing.

The interesting aspect of this question is: Just *HOW* is a metal attached to a semiconductor such that is does not form a shottky barrier (i.e. a diode) which a metal semi-conductor system will usually form.

The background theory is very interesting but it requires an understanding of Quantum mechanics, semi-conductor theory (fermi levels etc.) and processing knowledge.

For a N-Type contact, implants are formed in such a way that at the surface the semiconductor is degenerate (i.e. Metal like) so a Metal, Metal contact does not have a barrier.  Often these system will have silicides on them (refractory Si-Metal system)- to decrease the resistance) but that is not necessary here.  As the current moves into the substrate it experiences less and less doping (the band edges are gently distorted) until the carriers make it into the semiconductor.

For an P-Type contact, there are Quantum mechanical effects that allows for a tunnelling across the barrier (formed by the band gap ~ 1.12 eV), the rest of the trip from the conduction band edge up to the metal work function is explained by the same mechanism as used in a N-Type device (degenerately doped).  the Qm -effect is accomplished via a hyper abrupt metal - P material junction ( a few atoms deep at most).

Comment: The diodes on the A and B options are not oriented correctly for a physical device. The semiconductor material and doping on most mosfets is identical in the source and the drain and the metals used for contacting them is the same. So, if these were rectifying junctions, both diodes have to face the same way into the junction.